# Puzzling GCC behaviour with respect to vectorization and loop size

Tags: c++, c, gcc, vector, auto-vectorization

Initially investigating the effect of the `#pragma omp simd` directive, I came across a behaviour that I cannot explain, related to the vectorization of a simple for loop. The following code sample can be tested on this awesome [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#), provided the *-O3* directive is applied and we're on the x86 architecture.

Could anybody explain me the logic behind the following observations ?

```
#include <stdint.h> 

void test(uint8_t* out, uint8_t const* in, uint32_t length)
{
    unsigned const l1 = (length * 32)/32;  // This is vectorized
    unsigned const l2 = (length / 32)*32;  // This is not vectorized

    unsigned const l3 = (length << 5)>>5;  // This is vectorized
    unsigned const l4 = (length >> 5)<<5;  // This is not vectorized

    unsigned const l5 = length -length%32; // This is not vectorized
    unsigned const l6 = length & ~(32 -1); // This is not vectorized

    for (unsigned i = 0; i<l1 /*pick your choice*/; ++i)
    {
      out[i] = in[i*2];
    }
}
```

What puzzles me is that both l1 and l3 generate vectorized code in spite of not beeing guaranteed to be multiples of 32. All of the other lengths do *not* produce vectorized code, but should be multiples of 32. Is there a reason behind this ?

As an aside, using the #pragma omp simd directive doesn't actually change anything.

Edit: After further investigation, the difference of behaviour disappears when the index type is size_t (and no boundary manipulation is even needed), meaning that this generates vectorized code :

```
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <string>

void test(uint8_t* out, uint8_t const* in, size_t length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i<length; ++i)
    {
        out[i] = in[i*2];
    }
}
```

If somebody know why the loop vectorizing is so dependent on the index type then, I'd be curious to know more !

Edit2, thanks to Mark Lakata, O3 is actually needed

Comment: In what could be seen as an extension of this question, the exact same behaviour is visible with Clang, so I'm guessing that there's some logic to it.

Comment: It seems that the compiler is afraid that the index might wrap and gives up because of it :-(

Comment: The type dependence has been explained to me, linked to the risk of overflow (which prevents the vectorization). An unsigned overflow is allowed, while a signed overflow is not, which explains this last point. Using an unsigned and discarding the first bit (effectively killing the overflow risk) allows for vectorization, GCC is super smart : https://godbolt.org/g/SsVZ2r

Comment: @BenjaminLefaudeux There are no signed types in the example. `i*2` is always unsigned. And so is `i<length`.

Comment: @BenjaminLefaudeux Please then consider accepting the answer that made this clear, which I presume is that by 2501.

Comment: @underscore_d I would actually prefer if he didn't, as a proper answer should dive into assembly.

Comment: @2501 my edited example and remark with signed/unsigned was probably not clear enough, but if you test the second snippet with different types (like int/unsigned int for instance) you do get different results, which was explained to me by the overflow risk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is apparent conversion<sup>1</sup> from `unsigned` to `size_t` in the array index: `in[i*2];`

If you use `l1` or `l3` then the computation of `i*2` will always fit into the type `size_t`. This means that the type `unsigned` practically behaves as if it were `size_t`.

But when you use the other options, the result of the computation `i*2` can possibly not fit into  `size_t` as the value might wrap and the conversion must be made.

if you take your first example, not choosing options l1 or l3, and do the cast:

```
out[i] = in[( size_t )i*2];
```

the compiler optimizes, if you cast the whole expression:

```
out[i] = in[( size_t )(i*2)];
```

it doesn't.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Standard doesn't actually specify that the type in the index must be `size_t`, but it is a logical step from the compiler perspective.

Comment: I'm not sure indices get converted to `size_t` when dereferencing a pointer, though the possibility of overflow you talk about is still relevant

Comment: @GuyGreer According to the Standard they don't, see the update.

Comment: I still disagree with the problem being in any sort of conversion from `unsigned` to `size_t` (which on a 32 bit machine is a no-op).  Your answer makes much more sense to me stated in terms of dealing with wraparound and when the compiler can prove to itself that it won't happen.

Comment: @GuyGreer There is no conversion as far as C is concerned. I have clarified the wording.

Comment: @GuyGreer I also believe that it's a wrapping issue : in the case of l1/l3, the left bits are killed, so the compiler knows that there will be no overflow with the *2 (I had no idea that they were so smart..), so vectorization can be enabled. I think that's the reason why, at least it connects all the dots on my side (also the type dependence)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing optimization with vectorization. I used your [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#) and set -O2 for x86, and none of the examples are "vectorized".

Here is `l1`

```
test(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int):
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        andl    $134217727, %edx
        je      .L1
.L5:
        movzbl  (%rsi,%rax,2), %ecx
        movb    %cl, (%rdi,%rax)
        addq    $1, %rax
        cmpl    %eax, %edx
        ja      .L5
.L1:
        rep ret
```

Here is `l2`

```
test(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int):
        andl    $-32, %edx
        je      .L1
        leal    -1(%rdx), %eax
        leaq    1(%rdi,%rax), %rcx
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.L4:
        movl    %eax, %edx
        addq    $1, %rdi
        addl    $2, %eax
        movzbl  (%rsi,%rdx), %edx
        movb    %dl, -1(%rdi)
        cmpq    %rcx, %rdi
        jne     .L4
.L1:
        rep ret
```

That is not surprising, because what you are doing is essentially a "gather" load operation, where the load indices are not the same as the store indices. There is no support in x86 for gather/scatter. It is only introduced in AVX2 and AVX512, and that is not selected.

The slightly longer code is  dealing with the signed/unsigned issues, but there is no vectorization going on.

Comment: Thank for clarifying the vectorization. Can you elaborate on the signed/unsigned. The C source contains no signed types, so why would they be used in assembly?

Comment: well, i don't really know, but I'm guessing it has to do with limitations of the indirect load `movzbl(%rsi, %rax, 2), %ecx` and that %rax has to be less than 32 bits otherwise the scale of 2 will overflow. But I could not find the answer quickly on google...

Comment: fwiw, there is one signed value in your code. The constant 2 is signed ... but that doesn't matter in this discussion.

Comment: my bad, -O3 vectorizes, I'll correct the question. The compiler can optimize the loads by increasing the word size and discarding the odd subparts, that's a valid "vectorization" which, while not being as nice as a native interleaved load, has been present on x86 [for some time](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-packssdw.html).
As far as I'm concerned, the explanation dealing with the overflow risk explains everything